# Show that if $\frac{1}{\mu\left(E\right)}\cdot\int_{E}fd\mu\in C$ for all $E$ with $\mu\left(E\right)>0$ then $f\left(x\right)\in C$ almost surely

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I'm trying to prove the following claim but I really don't know where to start:

Let $\left(X,\mathcal{F},\mu\right)$
  be a finite measure space and let $f:\left(X,\mathcal{F}\right)\to\mathbb{R}$
  be a measurable function such that $\int_{X}\left|f\right|d\mu<\infty$
 . Suppose $C\subseteq\mathbb{R}$
  is a closed set such that $\frac{1}{\mu\left(E\right)}\cdot\int_{E}fd\mu\in C$
  for all $E\in\mathcal{F}$
  with $\mu\left(E\right)>0$
 . Show that $f\left(x\right)\in C$
  for almost all $x\in X$
  .

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Suppose $\mu(f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus C)) > 0$. $\mathbb{R}\setminus C$ is a countable disjoint union of open intervals, hence ...

Comment: @DanielFischer The one thing I could think of as a line of proof based on your hint is the equation $\mu\left(f^{-1}\left(\mathbb{R}\backslash C\right)\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu\left(f^{-1}\left(I_{n}\right)\right)$ when $I_{n}$ are disjoint intervals. I don't really see how to use that to reach a contradiction though so I'm suspecting this might not have been your line of thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\mu(f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus C)) > 0$, then, since $\mathbb{R}\setminus C$ is the disjoint union of countably many open intervals, there is an open interval $(a,b)$ in the complement of $C$ with $\mu(f^{-1}(a,b)) > 0$. Then there is a compact interval $[\alpha,\beta] \subset (a,b)$ with $\mu(f^{-1}([\alpha,\beta])) > 0$. For $E = f^{-1}([\alpha,\beta])$, we then have

$$\frac{1}{\mu(E)}\cdot\int_E f\,d\mu \in [\alpha,\beta],$$

which contradicts the assumption that the averages always lie in $C$.

Comment: Got it, $\alpha\mu\left(E\right)=\int_{E}\alpha d\mu\leq\int_{E}fd\mu\leq\int_{E}\beta d\mu=\beta\mu\left(E\right)
 $ which yields a contradiction. Thanks Daniel. Feel free to edit your proof to finality for posterity :)