# Show, that if the integral of f is non-negative for all subsets, then f is non-negative for mu-almost every x in X

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I've been struggling with part two of a problem for a while now, and is hoping someone can help me out.

The problem goes.

Let $(X, \mathcal{E}, \mu)$ be a measurable space and let $f$ be a function from $\mathcal{L}_{\mathbb{C}}^{1}(\mu)$

(a) Show, that if $\int_{A} f d \mu \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $A$ in $\mathcal{E},$ then $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ for $\mu$ -almost all $x$ in $X$

(b) Show, that if $\int_{A} f d \mu \in[0, \infty)$ for all $A$ in $\mathcal{E},$ then $f(x) \in[0, \infty)$ for $\mu$ -almost all $x$ in $X$

I have already shown part (a), but am stuck on part (b).

So far, I have used that $\int_A f d\mu$ = $\int_A f^+ d\mu + \int_A f^- d\mu \geq 0$. So I want to show that if
$$
\int_A f^+ d\mu \geq \int_A f^- d\mu \quad \forall A \in \mathcal{E}
$$
Then $f\geq0$ for $\mu$-almost every x in X.

But I haven't really been able to find a good way of showing this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579409/show-that-if-frac1-mu-lefte-right-cdot-int-efd-mu-in-c-for-all-e-wi?rq=1) help? eg take $ C = [ 0, \infty)$.

Comment: Sure does, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the link provided in the comments answers perfectly the question in a more general context i'll give a direct (standard) argument adjusted to the OP's question.

Let $A=\{x\in X:\, f(x)<0\}=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$ where $A_n=\{x\in X:\, f(x)<-1/n\}$. We claim that $\mu(A_n)=0$ for all $n$. Indeed, if this wasnt the case, then $\mu(A_{n_0})>0$ for some $n_0$. Then, $f(x)<-1/n_0$ for every $x\in A_{n_0}$ implies
$$\int_{A_{n_0}}f\,d\mu\leq -\frac{1}{n_0}\mu(A_{n_0})<0$$
But since $A_{n_0}\in \mathcal{E}$ this contradicts the fact that $\int_{A_{n_0}}f\,d\mu \geq 0$. Hence, $\mu(A_n)=0$ for all $n$. And now, $A_n$ being the union of $A$ we get $\mu(A)=0$. Hence, $f\geq 0$ for almost all $x\in X$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I actually almost got there, I created the set consisting of where f(x) < 0, and showed that it was a null set.